# ñ with UTF-8 and ASCII in PHP

Tags: php

I have two variables $var1=Ñ and $var2=Ñ. The $var1 according the function *mb_detect_encoding* is ASCII and the $var2 is utf-8. In the browser when I make *echo* of these variables I see Ñ and Ñ, i.e I see the two equals. But, when I compare these using if ($var1 == $var2) echo "OK"; else echo "KO". I get KO. I need a way to interpret that is the same symbol, Could you help me please?

Comment: Use [`iconv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) to convert one variable's encoding to be the same as the other's, then compare.